# What happens when TCP keepalive probe failed on an established socket?

Tags: sockets, unix, tcp

To be more clear, I am wondering what TCP would a socket be in when keepalive probe failed too many times?

For example right now I have the following for `netstat -anop`

`tcp        0      0 10.10.10.10:12345           11.11.11.11:56789        ESTABLISHED 12345/process    keepalive (7200.00/0/0)`

Let's say host `11.11.11.11` suddenly lost power forever, and host `10.10.10.10`'s keepalive probe will eventually detect the broken connection. When `10.10.10.10` detects the broken connection, what will the socket's state be in as shown by `netstat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection will be reset and the line will disappear from `netstat.`